# Return Response When First request failed And Try In Second Request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, interceptor

I try to explain the problem.in `App.js` I have Function `getUser` .when call this function.in first request get `401` error . For this reason in `axios.interceptors.response` I receive error `401`.At this time, I receive a token and repeat my request again.And it is done successfully.But not return response in  Function `getUser`.
I have hook for authentication and send request.

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const API_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:4000/api/";

function useJWT() {

  axios.interceptors.request.use(
    (request) => {
      request.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";
      console.log("request Send ");
      return request;
    },
    (error) => {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );
  axios.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
      console.log("answer = ", response);
      return response;
    },
    (error) => {
      if (error?.response?.status) {
        switch (error.response.status) {
          case 401:
            refreshToken().then((responseTwo) => {
              return
                sendPostRequest(
                  error.response.config.url
                    .split("/")
                    .findLast((item) => true)
                    .toString(),
                  error.response.config.data
              );
            });
            break;
          case 500:
            // Actions for Error 500
            throw error;
          default:
            console.error("from hook interceptor => ", error);
            throw error;
        }
      } else {
        // Occurs for axios error.message = 'Network Error'
        throw error;
      }
    }
  );

  const refreshToken = () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("refresh");
    return axios
      .post(API_URL + "token", {
        token,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.access) {
          localStorage.setItem("access", response.data.access);
        }
        if (response.data.refresh) {
          localStorage.setItem("refresh", response.data.refresh);
        }
        return response.data;
      });
  };

  function login(email, password) {
    return axios
      .post(API_URL + "login", {
        email,
        password,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.access) {
          localStorage.setItem("access", response.data.access);
        }
        if (response.data.refresh) {
          localStorage.setItem("refresh", response.data.refresh);
        }
        return response.data;
      });
  }

  const sendPostRequest = (url, data) => {
    console.log(300);
    const token = localStorage.getItem("access");
    axios.defaults.headers.common["jwt"] = token;

    return axios.post(API_URL + url, {
      data,
    });
  };

  const logout = () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("refresh");
    return axios
      .delete(API_URL + "logout", {
        token,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        localStorage.removeItem("access");
        localStorage.removeItem("refresh");
      });
  };

  return {
    login,
    logout,
    refreshToken,
    sendPostRequest,
  };
}

export default useJWT;
```

In App.js ,I want to repeat the same request again if a 401 error is issued when I read the user information.
The request is successfully repeated but does not return the value.
When first request fail response is return  equals null . and in catch when receive 401 error i am send second request but not return response.
I send request below code .

```
const getUser = () => {
 console.log(12);
 return sendPostRequest("user");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let token = localStorage.getItem("access");
    console.log("token = ", token);
    if (token != null) {
      //Here I have done simulation for 401 error
     localStorage.setItem("access", "");
       getUser()
         .then((response) => {
           console.log("response 1= ", response);
         })
    .catch((exception) => {
      console.log("exception = ", exception.toString());
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("response 2= ", response);
    });
} else {
  navigate("/login");
}
 }, []);
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find anwser for this question.
When error `401` occurs then create new `Promise` 
I Wrote this code.

```
case 401:
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          refreshToken().then((responseTwo) => {
            resolve(
              sendPostRequest(
                error.response.config.url
                  .split("/")
                  .findLast((item) => true)
                  .toString(),
                error.response.config.data
              )
            );
          });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't fully understand what exactly you want to do here.
But if you are looking to retry when `401` happens, you could use [axios-retry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-retry) to do it for you.

I'll pass the basics, but you can look more into what this does.

```
// First you need to create an axios instance
const axiosClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'API_URL',
  // not needed
  timeout: 30000
});

// Then you need to add this to the axiosRetry lib
axiosRetry(axiosClient, {
  retries: 3,
  // Doesn't need to be this, it can be a number in ms
  retryDelay: axiosRetry.exponentialDelay,
  retryCondition: (error) => {
  // You could do this way or try to implement your own
    return error.response.status > 400 
    // something like this works too.
    // error.response.status === 401 || error.response.status >= 500;
  }
});
```

Just like in your code, we need to use interceptors if you want to avoid breaking your page, otherwise you can use `try catch` to catch any errors that may happen in a request.

```
// It could be something like this, like I said, it's not really needed.
axiosClient.interceptors.response.use(
  (success) => success,
  (err) => err
);
```

And finally, you could use the `axiosClient` directly since it now has your `API_URL`, calling it like this `axiosClient.post('/user')`.

More or less that's it, you should just debug this code and see what is causing the return value to be null.
I would change these then/catch to be an async/await function, it would be more readable making your debugging easier.

`axios-retry` [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/axios-retry-example-h7b4jj?file=/src/App.js) if you didn't understand my explanation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use the new library in the project.I try to explain the problem.in ```App.js``` I have Function ```getUser``` .when call this function.in first request get 401 error . For this reason in ```axios.interceptors.response``` I receive error ```401```.At this time, I receive a token and repeat my request again.And it is done successfully.But not return response in  Function ```getUser```.